# Reference not found Exception in HornetQ

Tags: jms, hornetq

1. i am using hornetq with 200 threads consuming message at same time. some times i am getting below exception, as there is huge load on hornetq the below exception is triggered very often. please suggest me how to solve this.

17:18:29,622 ERROR [org.hornetq.core.server] HQ224016: Caught exception: HornetQException[errorType=ILLEGAL_STATE message=HQ119027: Could not find reference on consumer ID=0, messageId = 17,179,869,184 queue = jms.queue.ExampleQueue]
at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.ServerConsumerImpl.acknowledge(ServerConsumerImpl.java:704) [hornetq-server.jar:]
at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl.acknowledge(ServerSessionImpl.java:634) [hornetq-server.jar:]
at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.ServerSessionPacketHandler.handlePacket(ServerSessionPacketHandler.java:274) [hornetq-server.jar:]
at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.handlePacket(ChannelImpl.java:631) [hornetq-core-client.jar:]
at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.doBufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:547) [hornetq-core-client.jar:]
at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:523) [hornetq-core-client.jar:]
at org.hornetq.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:564) [hornetq-server.jar:]
at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.HornetQChannelHandler.messageReceived(HornetQChannelHandler.java:72) [hornetq-core-client.jar:]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88) [jboss-mc.jar:]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560) [jboss-mc.jar:]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787) [jboss-mc.jar:]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:281) [jboss-mc.jar:]
at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.HornetQFrameDecoder2.decode(HornetQFrameDecoder2.java:169) [hornetq-core-client.jar:]
at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.HornetQFrameDecoder2.messageReceived(HornetQFrameDecoder2.java:134) [hornetq-core-client.jar:]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [jboss-mc.jar:]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560) [jboss-mc.jar:]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:555) [jboss-mc.jar:]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [jboss-mc.jar:]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [jboss-mc.jar:]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioWorker.process(OioWorker.java:71) [jboss-mc.jar:]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.AbstractOioWorker.run(AbstractOioWorker.java:73) [jboss-mc.jar:]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioWorker.run(OioWorker.java:51) [jboss-mc.jar:]
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [jboss-mc.jar:]
at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [jboss-mc.jar:]
at org.jboss.netty.util.VirtualExecutorService$ChildExecutorRunnable.run(VirtualExecutorService.java:175) [jboss-mc.jar:]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version are you using?

This could been caused by you client message.acknowledge twice... or if you had a misuse of session boundaries. a Session is meant to belong to a thread. (that includes objects created within the session (consumer, producer.. etc).

you may switch threads.. but you have to keep a single thread to sessions.

Comment: As i am creating new session object for each thread. Still y i m getting this error?? please suggest me how to use java.concurrent with hornetq. thank you..

Comment: more on im using AUTO-ACKNOWLEDGE on consuming messages. sending ack twice can happen in AUTO-ACKNOWLEDGE mode??